# Using a proxy autoconfig script with an application that doesn't support it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, proxy, http, autoproxy

Is there a way to "Wrap" an application in such a way that outgoing HTTP traffic (i.e. web service calls) goes through a proxy that is configured via a [PAC script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)? The application itself has no built-in proxy support, much less PAC, so I'm guessing the outgoing packets would need to be intercepted and modified (so something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)). I don't care about HTTPS, just HTTP.

Possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/63099/supplying-http-proxy-support-to-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a product that fulfills all your requirements, but perhaps the combination of two products can come close. The problem is, that while products that socksify applications to proxies are plentiful, none of the products I found accepts a PAC script.

So it seems to me that the best hope for socksifying an application to a PAC script is in doing this in two steps :

1. Evaluate the PAC script against a URL - possible since the script is nothing more than a Javascript fragment
2. Update a proxy product with the result

**Possible products that evaluate PAC scripts are :**

[pacparser](http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/)
A library to parse proxy auto-config (PAC) files, which comes with a test program called 'pactester'.

[Proxytester](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/proxytest/index.php?title=Main_Page)
Open-source proxy list tester that generates a wpad.dat file that you can use in the browser.

**Possible products that proxify applications :**

[ProxyFirewall](http://proxyfirewall.org/)

> Force Your Programs to use a proxy at
>   the socket level. When it comes to
>   allowing packets to be sent out of
>   your computer, ProxyFirewall it will
>   not only allow you to choose if a
>   program is allowed to access the
>   Internet, but will also supply options
>   to force the connection through a
>   proxy server at the socket level.

[ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/) ($30)

> ProxyCap enables you to redirect your
>   computer's network connections through
>   proxy servers. You can tell ProxyCap
>   which applications will connect to the
>   Internet through a proxy and under
>   what circumstances. This is done
>   through a user friendly interface,
>   without the need to reconfigure any of
>   your Internet clients.

[Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) ($39.95)

> Proxifier is a program that allows
>   network applications that do not
>   support working through proxy servers
>   to operate through an HTTPS or SOCKS
>   proxy or a chain of proxy servers.

If one of the above products is parametrable via a text file, you may edit this file with the results of the PAC script evaluation, maybe by using [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), therefore achieving the proxification of the specified application according to the PAC script result.